# Deleting special character from a vector of strings C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, special-characters

I am trying to delete the special characters from a string which is in a vector. I am having trouble with how to exactly delete the special characters. I have a vector words; which contains words from plain text and I want to delete the special characters such as `?!.,;` etc. and also to delete spaces.

Comment: while ( infile >> word )
  {
   words.push_back ( word );
  }
With this i have filled the vector and what i get as a result is :

right?
wiliam"" etc i want to delete the special characters

Comment: Edit your question with the code, don't place into comments.

Answer (score 1):

Erasing single characters over and over is not very fast. The task can be done by creating new string and adding to it non-special characters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<string> words;
  words.push_back("");
  words.push_back("452346457");
  words.push_back(",.,;,;.;,;.;.?");
  words.push_back(";m;,./,/;,m;m,/,./,;");

  string special = string("?:,.;");

  for (string::size_type i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
  {
    string temp = words[i];
    words[i] = "";
    for (string::size_type j = 0; j < temp.size(); ++j)
    {
      if (special.find(temp[j]) == string::npos)
      {
        words[i] += temp[j];
      }
    }
  }

  for (string::size_type i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
  {
    cout << "\"" << words[i] << "\"\n";
  }
}
```

Notice the usage of very useful [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) function.

Comment: If the number of special characters is a large number, better to use a `std::set<char>` to store each special characters.  Then using `find` would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could go through your vector and use

```
for(int p = 0; p < words.size(); p++)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < words[p].length(); i++)
   { 
      if(words[p][i] == ' ' || ...)
      {
            words[p].erase(i, 1);
            i--;
      }
   }
}
```

Instead of `...` put the rest of the special characters that you want to erase, so it finds all of them.

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) is more information on erase. Basically, the first parameter is the position of the first character you want to erase, and the second parameter is the amount of characters to erase.

Comment: @FredLarson added correction, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

The general algorithm goes like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        vector<string> v;
        // get data into v

        for (auto& s : v){
          for (auto i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i){
             if (*i == '?' || *i == '!'){
                 i = s.erase(i);
             }
          }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This will miss characters.

Comment: How will it miss characters?

Comment: Because as soon as you erase a character your index is off by one.

Comment: Would it be enough to remove `++i` from the for loop and add it as an else statement below `s.erase(i, 1);`?  That way it won't increment if it performs `.erase()`.

Comment: It would be better to use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

Comment: I've edited it to that i is readjusted once the `erase()` occurs since `erase()` returns an iterator to the next character.

Comment: Isn't it still wrong though? `erase()` returns an iterator to the next character, and then `++i` is called at the end of the loop body to move to the next character after that.